# variable defined in one function and undefined in other typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

I have the following code:

```
class Currency {
    private counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    private dust = 0;
    private books = 0;
    private bookCounter = document.getElementById("books");
    
    constructor() {
        console.log("test")
        document.getElementById("bookbuy").addEventListener("click", this.buyBook)
    }

    public count() {
        this.dust ++;
        this.counter.innerHTML = "You have " + this.dust + " dust";
        console.log(this.dust)
    }

    public buyBook() {
        if (this.dust >= 10) {
            console.log("if works");
            this.dust - 10;
            this.books ++;
            this.counter.innerHTML = "You have " + this.dust + " dust";
            this.bookCounter.innerHTML = "You have " + this.books + " books";
        } else {
            console.log(this.dust)
        }
    }
  }

window.addEventListener("load", init);
function init(): void {
    const currency = new Currency();
    setInterval(() => {currency.count();}, 1000);
}
```

the console.log in count() is defined and working fine, but when i try to use this.dust in buyBook() it returns as undefined.
Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: The `this`, within the context of the `buyBook` when called as the event handler of a click for `bookbuy`, will be the `bookbuy` element, not your class.

Comment: You could change it wrap the method call to preserve the context.  `.addEventListener("click", () => this.buyBook())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to bind the this context for buyBook, or the event handler will redefine the this context.

Edit: Also, I think you meant to decrement 10 from `this.dust` not just subtract 10

```
class Currency {
    private counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    private dust = 0;
    private books = 0;
    private bookCounter = document.getElementById("books");
    
    constructor() {
        console.log("test")
        document.getElementById("bookbuy").addEventListener("click", this.buyBook.bind(this))
    }

    public count() {
        this.dust ++;
        this.counter.innerHTML = "You have " + this.dust + " dust";
        console.log(this.dust)
    }

    public buyBook() {
        if (this.dust >= 10) {
            console.log("if works");
            this.dust -= 10;
            this.books ++;
            this.counter.innerHTML = "You have " + this.dust + " dust";
            this.bookCounter.innerHTML = "You have " + this.books + " books";
        } else {
            console.log(this.dust)
        }
    }
  }

window.addEventListener("load", init);
function init(): void {
    const currency = new Currency();
    setInterval(() => {currency.count();}, 1000);
}
```